# OMD vs Ubuntu install issues

Tags: ubuntu, monitoring, nagios, check-mk

When installing OMD 1.3 on Ubuntu, I get the following output

> dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of omd-1.31.20160708: 
>   omd-1.31.20160708 depends on libapache2-mod-proxy-html; however:
>   Package libapache2-mod-proxy-html is not installed.  omd-1.31.20160708
>   depends on apache2-mpm-prefork; however:   Package apache2-mpm-prefork
>   is not installed.  omd-1.31.20160708 depends on
>   libboost-program-options1.54.0; however:   Package
>   libboost-program-options1.54.0 is not installed.  omd-1.31.20160708
>   depends on libboost-system1.54.0; however:   Package
>   libboost-system1.54.0 is not installed.  omd-1.31.20160708 depends on
>   libperl5.18; however:   Package libperl5.18 is not installed. 
>   omd-1.31.20160708 depends on php5-cli; however:   Package php5-cli is
>   not installed.  omd-1.31.20160708 depends on php5-cgi; however:
>   Package php5-cgi is not installed.  omd-1.31.20160708 depends on
>   php5-gd; however:   Package php5-gd is not installed. 
>   omd-1.31.20160708 depends on php5-mcrypt; however:   Package
>   php5-mcrypt is not installed.  omd-1.31.20160708 depends on
>   php5-sqlite; howeve dpkg: error processing package omd-1.31.20160708
>   (--install):  dependency problems - leaving unconfigured

I have updated and upgraded my system a million times and still issue persists and has confirmed that the dependencies exist
Does anybody know if the above packages and their versions is required?
I have the dependencies installed, but on the latest version and I am assuming that OMD and the packages that comes with it requires the older version?

Any advise or solutions to this issue?
System:Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS
OMD Version: 1.31.20160708

Answer (score 0):

1. download the right version of check_mk, for Ubuntu 16.04:
2. **https://mathias-kettner.de/support/1.4.0p16/check-mk-raw-1.4.0p16_0.xenial_amd64.deb**

   3. root@linux# apt-get install gdebi-core
   4. root@linux# gdebi check-mk-raw-1.4.0p16_0.xenial_amd64.deb
   5. root@linux# a2enmod proxy_http
   6. root@linux# /etc/init.d/apache2 restart
   7. root@linux# omd create mysite
   8. root@linux# su - mysite

Now you are in the OMD and you can go to check_mk folder in: cd local/share/check_mk